# Rails - Just want all the functions being called in console or logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xdebug

I want to trace without external gem like debugger, pry, or buybug.

I want to print just the function name when its called.

One way is writing another code to find def and appending puts "function name" in every file. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ruby document: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

You can use following debugger,

1. web-console gem
2. byebug gem
3. Rails Logger